# Visual Studio Team Services Web.Config substitute variables

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, devops

Before I was shown Octopus Deploy I thought that environment dependent appSettings should be a part of Build Configuration in project properties.

Now in times of software as a service it is a deployment process that buckles everything up.

I want my environment configuration in release process to just open web.config and substitute appsettings and connection strings based on variable names i defined for the release definition.

How can I do it? The closest I could get was Magic chunks. The problem with it is that I have to give it a json with the mapping and I have to define it for each environment separately, so it makes no use of environment variables, really, or at least you have to define it in "enviroment variables" section and then, again, in each process of environment.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Tokenizer" task in ["Release Management Utility tasks"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks) extension or ["Replace Tokens"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task.

These tasks can replace the strings in a file with the custom variables in definition.

Comment: Yes but you cannot keep tokens in web.config because developers need to run the apps on localhosts.

Comment: @doker You can use it with SlowCheetah transformation together by add one more configurations: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: That's cool, still. I bilieve that source code should be totally environment agnostic. The build process should set the right values for target environment.